# Find next opening hours if shop currently close

Tags: php, time

I have an array of opening hours and I'm trying to work out how to find out when a store next opens.

My array looks like

```
$storeSchedule = [
    'Sun' => ['12:00 AM' => '01:00 AM'],
    'Mon' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Tue' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Wed' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Thu' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Fri' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Sat' => ['12:00 AM' => '01:00 AM']
];
```

The difficult part is Saturday, which is at the end of the array, which reopens on Sunday at 12:00am.

Can anyone help, or point me in the right direction please.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ?

Comment: The shop opens for one hour in the middle of the night on weekends? What are you selling?

Comment: @Akshay like the question stats "Find next opening hours if shop currently close"

Comment: @Darragh it's ... umm .... test data? ;)

Comment: Are you sure the shop opens just once a day, and always closes the same day?

Comment: @nl-x Yes. The shop doesn't close for lunch and usually shuts 5pm.

Comment: @dotty : you are saying `Thu' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM']` does that mean that it opens Thursday at 9:00AM and closes Thursday at 12:00AM ? If so, are you aware that 12:00AM comes BEFORE 9:00AM ?

Answer (score 2):

You use date('D') to get the abbreviated weekday.

And you use array_keys()/array_values() to get hte keys/values of the inner arrays.

```
<?php
$today_opening = array_keys($storeSchedule[date('D')]);
$today_opening = $today_opening [0];
$today_closing = array_values($storeSchedule[date('D')]);
$today_closing = $today_closing [0];
$tomorrow_opening = array_keys($storeSchedule[date('D', time()+24*60*60)]);
$tomorrow_opening = $tomorrow_opening [0];

if (strtotime("today " . $today_opening) > time())
    echo "Opens at " . $today_opening;
elseif (strtotime("today " . $today_closing) > time())
    echo "Still open until " . $today_closing;
else
    echo "Opens tomorrow at " . $tomorrow_opening;
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `date('w')` which gives today's week number, which is 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday. You can modify your code like this:

```
$storeSchedule = [
    0 => ['12:00 AM' => '01:00 AM'],
    1 => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    2 => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    3 => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    4 => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    5 => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    6 => ['12:00 AM' => '01:00 AM']
];

// tomorrow's week number
$tomorrow = date('w') + 1;
if ($tomorrow > 6) { // On Saturdays, the above statement will return 7
    $tomorrow = 0;   // Set manually to Sunday's code
}

$openingHours = $storeSchedule[$tomorrow];
print_r($openingHours);
```

Comment: Anyway to keep the array keys as they are?

Comment: You shouldn't call date('w') the 'week number, as that is confusing. It is the number of the day of the week. date('W') with capital W gives the week number however. Also beware that the opening hours are the KEY of the inner array, not the VALUE of the inner array.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is sufficient, but the shop will next open the next day so:-

```
    $storeSchedule = array(
        'Sun' => array('12:00 AM','01:00 AM'),
        'Mon' => array('09:00 AM','12:00 AM'),
        'Tue' => array('09:00 AM','12:00 AM'),
        'Wed' => array('09:00 AM','12:00 AM'),
        'Thu' => array('09:00 AM','12:00 AM'),
        'Fri' => array('09:00 AM','12:00 AM'),
        'Sat' => array('12:00 AM','01:00 AM')
    );

    $next=date('D', strtotime('+1 day') );
    $times=$storeSchedule[ $next ];
    $openingtime=$times[0];
    $closingtime=$times[1];

    echo 'Next opens: ' . $next . ' @' . $openingtime.' and closes @'.$closingtime;
```

I rejigged the array slightly and because of the version of php i use I can't use the new [] syntax - hence old stylee.

Alternatively, using key->value pairs as original

```
$storeSchedule = array(
    'Sun' => array('12:00 AM'=>'01:00 AM'),
    'Mon' => array('09:00 AM'=>'12:00 AM'),
    'Tue' => array('09:00 AM'=>'12:00 AM'),
    'Wed' => array('09:00 AM'=>'12:00 AM'),
    'Thu' => array('09:00 AM'=>'12:00 AM'),
    'Fri' => array('09:00 AM'=>'12:00 AM'),
    'Sat' => array('12:20 AM'=>'01:00 AM')
);
$next=date('D', strtotime('+1 day') );
$times=$storeSchedule[ $next ];

$keys=array_keys( $times );
$values=array_values( $times );

$openingtime=$keys[0];
$closingtime=$values[0];

    echo 'Next opens: ' . $next . ' @' . $openingtime.' and closes @'.$closingtime;
```

Comment: Beware that in his array, the opening hours are KEYS of array elements, and the closing hours are VALUES of array element.